# Big O (Asymptotic run time), is 3^n = O(2^n)?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am going through a course that gave an example function of (100033)<sup>3n</sup>. It didn't give any explanation other than:

> For an exponential function, the coefficient of the exponent is irrelevant to assessing the growth of the function, so the asymptotic run function is usually expressed as 2<sup>n</sup>. So, the asymptotic run time function for f(n)=(100033)<sup>3n</sup> is 2<sup>n</sup>.

And then it gave another example problem of f(n)=3<sup>n</sup>+2<sup>n</sup>. For this example, it said:

> we can ignore 2<sup>n</sup> because 3<sup>n</sup> is larger and the asymptotic run time is 3<sup>n</sup>.

However, after ignoring 2<sup>n</sup> we are left with 3<sup>n</sup> which is exponential and if I follow the logic of the first example, since 3<sup>n</sup> is exponential wouldn't it mean that the asymptotic run time of it is 2<sup>n</sup>?

I am a beginner, and this book hasn't explained any of the math behind why any of this works. So I am just applying the logic the book gave me.

Comment: Are you sure this is in the context of big-O? Because it is not true: *O(n^2)* and *O(n^3)* are different complexity classes. The second example is true though. Are you able to provide us with the book or its exact quote?

Comment: Can you name the book you are referring to? Maybe a link to an online bookstore or an online version?

Answer (score 2):

The text you quoted makes a wrong claim:

> So, the asymptotic run time function for f(n)=(100033)^3n is 2^n

This is false. It is true that the positive coefficient that multiplies  can be removed when looking at the asymptotic run time, and so

() = 100033<sup>3</sup> is O(100033)

But one cannot reduce the *base* of the exponentiation:

() is not O(2)

### Proof that 3 is not O(2)

We can prove this point using the definition of [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Let's say () = 3 and we want to see whether () is O(2). Then we should be able to find constants  and  such that:

3 ≤  (2) for all  >

Let's play with that constraint:

(3/2) ≤  for all  >

Or:

≤ log<sub><sub>3/2</sub></sub> for all  >

... which is a contradiction. "all  > " means we can choose  to be some value greater than log<sub><sub>3/2</sub></sub>. And that violates the constraint.

The conclusion is that () = 100033<sup>3</sup> is **not** O(2), and the text you quoted is wrong in that claim.

The second quote from the book is a correct statement:

When we have () = 3 + 2, we can drop the second term, as the first term is asymptotically greater than the second, and so we can say () is O(3).

#### The rules of asymptotic complexity

In summary, if  and  are positive **constants** then:

is O()

But if  > 1:

() is not O()

With concrete values of  and  (2 and 1.5):

2<sup>1.5</sup> is O(2)

But:

3 is not O(2)